# Reset running sum when condition is met in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My data is structured as follows:

```
Timestamp   | Hour | Count
--------------------------
20190801 01 |    1 |    10
20190801 02 |    2 |    20
20190801 03 |    3 |    10
20190801 04 |    4 |     5
20190801 05 |    5 |    15
20190801 06 |    6 |    10
20190802 01 |    1 |     5
20190802 02 |    2 |    20
20190802 03 |    3 |     5
20190802 04 |    4 |    15
20190802 05 |    5 |    20
20190802 06 |    6 |     5
20190803 01 |    1 |    30
```

I'm trying to make an SQL query that will calculate a running SUM but resets when the hour is 1.  The result should look like this:

```
Hour | Count | SUM
------------------
   1 |    10 |  10
   2 |    20 |  30
   3 |    10 |  40
   4 |     5 |  45
   5 |    15 |  60
   6 |    10 |  70
   1 |     5 |   5    /* RESET */
   2 |    20 |  25
   3 |     5 |  30    
   4 |    15 |  45
   5 |    20 |  65
   6 |     5 |  70
   1 |    30 |  30    /* RESET */
```

Comment: is there any other column to specify *row order*?

Comment: So the Hour column is actually a TIMESTAMP column.  It should be ordered in ASC order for this problem

Comment: Does this table has an `ID` (PK)?

Comment: Hour can be used as an ID.  Think of it as a TIMESTAMP column but i did a TO_CHAR ('hh24')  on it

Comment: @KaiserWilhelm Nope, it can't be, an ID means a PK while the Hour column can't be a PK. The `ID` must identify a row. In your sample none of the columns is an ID

Comment: I will edit my question to make this more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum()` analytic function :

```
select t."Hour","Count",
       sum("Count") over (partition by substr("Timestamp",1,8) order by "Timestamp") as "sum"
  from t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f4b82ce68fc47f9cdc2bb8934fc72d46)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to make it a bit more difficult. How can i do this if the reset is in the middle of the day? say 3 o'clock?

Comment: @KaiserWilhelm sorry but you should ask another question,please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57530417/reset-sum-when-condition-is-met-in-oracle